# react props undefined inside the constructor and exist inside the render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a controlled text area.

```
class TextArea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
        text: this.props.initial
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

handleChange(event) {
    //some handle
}

render() {
    return (
        <textarea
          value={this.state.text}
          placeholder={this.props.initial}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

For some reason if I console.log the `this.props.initial` in the constructor I get an undefined.

But the placeholder works.

What I would like to do is to ditch the placeholder and set an initial value to that the user can edit and copy and interact with. (basically normal text and not a placeholder, but I cannot do that because it doesn't work)

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
The way that I am passing `props.initial` to the textarea:

```
<TextArea
  initial={this.state.json.initial}
  text={this.state.json.text}
  changeHandler={this.handleChange}
/>
```

I am getting the json from a $.getJSON call and I think that the textarea gets rendered before the json call is finished. Is there any way to run the render function only after the componentWillMount function?

Comment: Remove `this` from `this.props` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Can't you just use `props.initial` in your constructor?

Comment: super is building the this correctly so this shouldn't change anything

Comment: @mersocarlin I tried that and it still didn't work

Comment: @Wolfyaskingstuff Please check my answer. I used your code as example and it is working :)

Comment: @Wolfyaskingstuff Could you show how you are passing `initial` prop to `TextArea`?

Comment: @Prakashsharma added it to my post.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `this` from `this.props` in the constructor since you have access to `props` from its argument list.

```js
class TextArea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {
      text: props.initial,
    }
    
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
  
  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({ text: event.target.value })
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Initial text: {this.props.initial}</div>
        <textarea
          value={this.state.text}
          placeholder={this.props.initial}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TextArea />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This works great if I put a string instead of props.initial, but it still is just an undefined.

Comment: I don’t get it. What do you want to do? Are you sending a string as `initial` prop or not?

Comment: I am sending a string. I meant that if I sent a hard-coded string it worked, if I sent the initial prop (also a string) it doesn't

Comment: Can you `console.log(this.state.json)` and check whether it's defined or not?

Answer (score 0):

the important part to understand is that the constructor already takes in the props as parameters so you can access props directly in the constructor as `props`. no need to access it via `this.props` as long as you are inside the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state= {
    text: props.initial
  }
}
```

the code above should work

---

However, this is a better way of structuring a component like `TextArea` and it should also solve your problem of `props.initial` not having a value on runtime

First, you need to prepare the `handleChange` method in the parent component

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      myTextArea: ''
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange (e) {
    this.setState({myTextArea: e.target.value})
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <TextArea
        value={myTextArea}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

and on the text area component, you refer to onchange method passed through the props when defining the onchange method of your textarea.

```
<textarea
  value={this.props.value}
  placeholder="Something"
  onChange={this.props.handleChange}
/>
```

---

the benefit of this approach is that one, the one that calls the textarea will always have an updated value, and two, this child element doesnt need to have a state. it makes managing a large react app easier and its the correct mind set to have once you start trying to implement Redux or similar frameworks to handle your state for you

Comment: @Wolfyaskingstuff have you tried planting a `debugger` in the constructor then checking there if `props.initial` has value when the constructor is run? it might be possible that `props` is being populated at a later time

Comment: It does exactly that but I have no idea why

Comment: so it had value when the constructor is run? if not there are other workarounds to this like having the parent component provide `TextArea` an onchange method which would be used. I can modify my answer to show just that if you want to try it out

Comment: Also it does not have value when the constructor is run

Comment: @Wolfyaskingstuff i update my answer with a better way to structure your react code. i hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to garantee that this.props.inital exists:

```
{ this.state.json && this.state.json.initial &&
  <TextArea initial={this.state.json.initial} text={this.state.json.text} changeHandler={this.handleChange}/>
}
```

Comment: I actually added an edit to my post that explains why they are undefined. I just need to solve another problem now